# Can't find new.h - getting gcc-4.2 on Quantal?

Tags: 12.10, gcc, g++

I've been trying to compile the Valve Source SDK (2007) on my machine, but I keep running into the same error:

```
In file included from ../public/tier1/interface.h:50:0,
             from ../utils/serverplugin_sample/serverplugin_empty.cpp:13:
             ../public/tier0/platform.h:46:17: new.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty new to C++ coding and compiling, but using `apt-file search` I tried to use every single suggestion for the required files in the Makefile (`libstdc++.a` and `libgcc_eh.a`), and none worked. I then found a note in the Makefile saying gcc 4.2.2 is recommended - I assume the older code won't work with the newer version, but gcc-4.2 is unavailable in 12.10.

So my question/s is/are:
If my assumption is right - how do I get gcc 4.2.2 on Quantal?
If my assumption is wrong - what else could be the problem here?

Relevant portion of the Makefile:

```
# compiler options (gcc 3.4.1 will work - 4.2.2 recommended)
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
CPLUS=/usr/bin/g++
CLINK=/usr/bin/gcc
CPP_LIB="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/libstdc++.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/libgcc_eh.a"

# GCC 4.2.2 optimization flags, if you're using anything below, don't use these!
OPTFLAGS=-O1 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fforce-addr -funroll-loops -fthread-jumps -fcrossjumping -foptimize-sibling-calls -fcse-follow-jumps -fcse-skip-blocks -fgcse -fgcse-lm -fexpensive-optimizations -frerun-cse-after-loop -fcaller-saves -fpeephole2 -fschedule-insns2 -fsched-interblock -fsched-spec -fregmove -fstrict-overflow -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -freorder-blocks -freorder-functions -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels -ftree-vrp -ftree-pre -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fgcse-after-reload
#OPTFLAGS=

# put any compiler flags you want passed here
USER_CFLAGS=-m32
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just installed Hardy and installed gcc-4.2 there. The error is not happening now, so that was the problem. I'm running into others now, but I assume they are not related to the compiler.